# Create a document with source code of the project

Tags: text, documentation

I have a project with a lot of source code. For documentation purposes, I must merge all source code into a single file, for instance, PDF, HTML or DOCX. Preferably, each merged file content should have a caption with its relative origin. Nice formatting is desired but not obligatory.

Did anybody ever do this task? Is there any simple code snippet to automate the task? Strangely, I searched around and did not find any hints on this challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on something UNIXish, [a2ps](https://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/) does a really nice job printing large amounts of sources to postscript, which is then trivial to convert to PDF via e.g. [ps2pdf](http://ghostscript.com/doc/7.07/Ps2pdf.htm).  Something like:

```
a2ps *.c -o foo.ps
ps2pdf foo.ps foo.pdf
```

This will dump all sources you specify on the command line (and you can go recursive with some combo of find and xargs or similar).  If you don't need a total source dump, you're probably best off reading up on your language's native source documenter (like doxygen or javadoc or similar).  Most source documenter systems can output to bunches of formats ime.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I m actually on Windows but it should be not a problem to run any unix stuff. I suspected myself that unix is more tailored to this type of task. I will give it a try and update on results.

Comment: I used windows port of a2ps (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/a2ps.htm) and it worked really nice. I definitely recommend it in similar situations. Thanks again!

Comment: You are very welcome, sir!